# Как проверить правильно что одно из полей заполнено?

Tags: java, android

Не могу сообразить как правильно написать условие. У меня есть 3 editText , скажем 1, 2, 3

Так вот если 1 или 2 заполнен то 3 не нужно проверять если 1 или 2 пустой то нужно

Вот так у меня вышло

```
boolean isOneExist = !TextUtils.isEmpty(one);
boolean isTwoExist = !TextUtils.isEmpty(two);

if (!isOneExist || !isTwoExist) { //check editText 3 }
```

Как правило вводится текст в 1 или в 2 и получается так что всегда одно значение получается true другое false и я не пойму как сделать правильно

Вроде должно быть просто

Comment: `Но всегда одно значение получается true другое false` – приведите пример.

Comment: @post_zeew добавил в вопрос

Comment: _1 или 2 заполнен то 3 не нужно проверять, если 1 или 2 пустой то нужно_ - Вы понимаете, что когда один из двух заполнен, то так же один из двух пустой? Следовательно ваше условие верно только когда оба заполнены

Comment: @AGS17 нет, 1 или 2 заполнен то не нужно, если 1 и 2 пустой то нужно... Код не заходит в блок `if`  только если заполнено поле и 1 и 2 , но это не то, что мне нужно как вы понимаете... Мне нужно чтоб по одному заполненному полу (либо 1 либо 2) блок `if` не выполнялся

Comment: @AGS17 или  я не так вас понял?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko вам таблички нарисовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании логического **ИЛИ** (`||`) получается, что условие выполняется тогда, когда хотя бы одно поле пустое (то есть либо первое, либо второе, либо оба).

Для проверка третьего поля только в случае, когда оба первых поля пустые, нужно использовать **И** (`&&`):

```
if (!isOneExist && !isTwoExist)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Также можно избавиться от двойного отрицания:

```
boolean isOneEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(one);
boolean isTwoEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(two);
if (isOneEmpty && isTwoEmpty)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1 или 2 заполнен то 3 не нужно проверять, если 1 или 2 пустой - то нужно

Такого не может быть, что будет заполнен один из них, но не будет пустых.

Для наглядности ваши текст боксы могут быть:

```
          | пустой | заполненный
TextBox 1 |   +    |      -
TextBox 2 |   +    |      -
---------------------------------
TextBox 1 |   +    |      -
TextBox 2 |   -    |      +
---------------------------------
TextBox 1 |   -    |      +
TextBox 2 |   +    |      -
---------------------------------
TextBox 1 |   -    |      +
TextBox 2 |   -    |      +
```

Вы же просите это:

```
          | пустой | заполненный
TextBox 1 |   -    |      +
TextBox 2 |   -    |      -
---------------------------------
TextBox 1 |   -    |      -
TextBox 2 |   -    |      +
```

Разберем ваше условие:

> 1 или 2 заполнен то 3 не нужно проверять

Если 1 или 2 заполнен, то 2 или 1 будет пустой соответственно.

> если 1 или 2 пустой - то нужно

Если 1 или 2 пустой - то 2 или 1 будет заполнен соответственно.

### **UPD:**

Согласно [комментарию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668778/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE#comment970418_668778), все же требуется проверять на 2 пустых поля. Соответственно, могу предложить повысить читаемость кода:

```
boolean isFirstEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(one);
boolean isSecondEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(two);

if (isFirstEmpty && isSecondEmpty ) { //check editText 3 }
```

Comment: в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668778/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be#comment970418_668778) уже "1 **или** 2 заполнен то не нужно, если 1 **и** 2 пустой то нужно"

Comment: @pavlofff я ожидал, что в вопросе будут верные кондишены.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
    boolean empty = TextUtils.isEmpty(one);
    empty &= TextUtils.isEmpty(two);
    if (empty) { //check editText 3 }
```